# Self join not returning rows when only single row

Tags: t-sql

Shown below is a snippet of a resident admit-discharge status table. 
 I am trying to filter out residents whose date (admit/readmit date) 
 is at least 30 days after their last discharge.

The code below seems to be working fine except when there is only one row for the resident.
  Resident 200 (see table) has only one entry and hence not returned by query.

How do I get the query to return this row ??
Left and Right joins don't give the right results.

```
 ;with sorted as 
  (
     select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by rsa.cono,rsa.resno order by rsa.sort desc) rn,rsa.*
  from ri_status_admit rsa 
 )

select   s1.cono,s1.resno,s1.rn,s1.date,s1.admit_disch,s2.date,s2.rn,
                s2.admit_disch,datediff(dd,s2.date, s1.date)
         from sorted s1 
             join sorted s2
         on 
              s1.cono = s2.cono
              and s1.resno = s2.resno 
              and s1.admit_disch in ('A','R')
              and s2.rn = s1.rn + 1
              and datediff(dd,s2.date, s1.date) >= 30 


 rn cono    resno   date            sort    admit_disch
 1  01     145     7/5/2009     73047           D
 2  01     145     11/23/2007    4872           R
 3  01     145     11/19/2007    54797          D
 4  01     145     4/21/2007    48403           R
 5  01     145     4/20/2007    48400           D
 1  01     152     1/4/2010     77674           D
 2  01     152     6/1/2001        97           A
 1  01     170     9/15/2009    74881           D
 2  01     170     5/15/2004    18733           R
 3  01     170     5/12/2004    18666           D
 4  01     170     3/1/2004     17014           R
 5  01     170     2/17/2004    16686           D
 6  01     170     1/2/2001       104           A
 1  01     200     1/4/2017       100           A
```

Comment: left join should give you correct results... probably missed an `isnull` somewhere.

Comment: Based on your text I don't think this is correct.  s2 is not limited to D records.  You could get a hit on A R difference >= 30

Comment: @paparazzo - There is always a 'D' row before a 'A' or 'R' row except when there is a single row - in which case it will be a 'A'

Comment: But there is nothing in the query that assure that.  If your data is not as expected (it happens) the query can be wrong.

Comment: I didn't add it to the query, because a resident cannot be Admitted/Re-admitted without being discharged (unless its the first admit) and the system takes take of that - I have already check that.

Comment: The system is designed to take care of that.  Systems can fail.  Is there any harm to the query validating that?  It would also make the query more efficient.

Comment: That assumption fails on even the existing records.  Sort on rsa.cono, rsa.resno,  rsa.sort desc and the first two record are 'D'

Answer (score 0):

You can switch the `INNER JOIN` for a `LEFT JOIN` and force the join in the `WHERE` with a conditional `EXISTS`.

```
;with sorted as 
  (
     select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by rsa.cono,rsa.resno order by rsa.sort desc) rn,rsa.*
  from ri_status_admit rsa 
 )

select   s1.cono,s1.resno,s1.rn,s1.date,s1.admit_disch,s2.date,s2.rn,
                s2.admit_disch,datediff(dd,s2.date, s1.date)
         from sorted s1 
             left join sorted s2
         on 
              s1.cono = s2.cono
              and s1.resno = s2.resno 
              and s1.admit_disch in ('A','R')
              and s2.rn = s1.rn + 1
              and datediff(dd,s2.date, s1.date) >= 30 
        where
            s2.resno IS NOT NULL OR -- Force an inner join or...
            NOT EXISTS 
                (SELECT 1 FROM sorted AS S
                 WHERE s.resno = s1.resno AND s.cono = s1.cono AND S.rn = 2) -- Include standalone resno/cono
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see this is something is just not correct. There is an assumption there is always a 'D' row before a 'A' or 'R' which is true for this data.  But there are is also two D rows in a row. The reverse assumption a D row is followed by and A or R is not true.

```
 declare @T table (cono int, resno int, dt  date, sort int, a_d char(1))
 insert into @T values 
        (01, 145, '7/5/2009',   73047, 'D')
      , (01, 145, '11/23/2007',  4872, 'R')
      , (01, 145, '11/19/2007', 54797, 'D')
      , (01, 145, '4/21/2007',  48403, 'R')
      , (01, 145, '4/20/2007',  48400, 'D')
      , (01, 152, '1/4/2010',   77674, 'D')
      , (01, 152, '6/1/2001',      97, 'A')
      , (01, 170, '9/15/2009',  74881, 'D')
      , (01, 170, '5/15/2004',  18733, 'R')
      , (01, 170, '5/12/2004',  18666, 'D')
      , (01, 170, '3/1/2004',   17014, 'R')
      , (01, 170, '2/17/2004',  16686, 'D')
      , (01, 170, '1/2/2001',     104, 'A')
      , (01, 200, '1/4/2017',     100, 'A');
select t.* 
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by cono, resno order by sort desc) as rn
 from @T t
order by cono, resno, sort desc 

cono        resno       dt         sort        a_d  rn
----------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ---- --------------------
1           145         2009-07-05 73047       D    1
1           145         2007-11-19 54797       D    2
1           145         2007-04-21 48403       R    3
1           145         2007-04-20 48400       D    4
1           145         2007-11-23 4872        R    5
1           152         2010-01-04 77674       D    1
1           152         2001-06-01 97          A    2
1           170         2009-09-15 74881       D    1
1           170         2004-05-15 18733       R    2
1           170         2004-05-12 18666       D    3
1           170         2004-03-01 17014       R    4
1           170         2004-02-17 16686       D    5
1           170         2001-01-02 104         A    6
1           200         2017-01-04 100         A    1
```